# Find the Electronic Configuration of an Iron Atom

Tags: electronic-configuration, erratum

I'm confused. Iron has 26 electrons and I wrote down $\ce{1s^2, 2s^2, 2p^6, 3s^2, 3p^6, 4s^2, 3d^6}$ yet my answer booklet says $\ce{1s^2, 2s^2, 2p^6, 3s^2, 3p^6}$ but that is only 18. How can it be 18 if $\ce{Fe}$ (iron) is 26? What am I doing wrong?

Thank You

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer summarises in you're right and book wrong.

Comment: @Mithoron - I disagree. RTStriker made a huge mistake. *"What am I doing wrong? "* **You believed the book was infallible.** ;-)

Comment: Many books have an erratum list somewhere. You might try to look yours up for other stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Mithoron I'd leave it open. It's a good example for an  acceptable homework question: RTStriker describes their assignment, their own solution AND the reason for their doubts. I don't see, why "your book is wrong" was a valid close reason.

Comment: @Marzipanherz No, this is example of question, that even if not closed, should get later deleted in "[Spring Cleaning](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/introducing-spring-cleaning)"

Comment: I agree with Mithoron on that the question is not useful; and therefore I will close it. The configuration can easily looked up on the internet, e.g. [here](https://www.webelements.com/iron/). Without the source (complete quote and full citation) it is also not helpful as a reference to future users of your book.